# Can you modify NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion in the iPhone App Info.plist programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ssl

I use Charles to debug my app requests and responses and it doesn't use the latest version of TLS (which iOS 9 does).  Is there a way to update this programmatically so that I can enable it for only local builds done through Xcode?  I have a Jenkins build server that still needs to use the new version of TLS.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little messy, but you can use the command line tool PlistBuddy in a Run Script step to accomplish that. Messy because it leaves the actual info.plist changed, so you'll see it in a git history.

The script below will add the exception only on DEBUG builds, and remove any ATS exceptions otherwise. You could edit it to be more specific, or just always add/remove the blanket `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` flag.

```
# Remove exception for all builds
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :NSAppTransportSecurity" ${INFOPLIST_FILE} 2>/dev/null
exitCode=$? #Supresses failure if key doesn't exist

# Add exception for Debug builds
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]
then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :NSAppTransportSecurity dict" ${INFOPLIST_FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSExceptionDomains dict" ${INFOPLIST_FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSExceptionDomains:<host> dict" ${INFOPLIST_FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSExceptionDomains:<host>:NSIncludesSubdomains bool true" ${INFOPLIST_FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSExceptionDomains:<host>:NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads bool true" ${INFOPLIST_FILE}
fi
```

More info http://product.reverb.com/2015/06/29/ios-9-and-charles-proxy/

Comment: Possible to modify ATS settings at runtime?